# Inconsistent handling of downvotes for reputation cap between site and /reputation page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-cap, rep-recalc

From my reputation development yesterday, I believe there is an inconsistency between how the site treats downvote reputation loss, and how it's treated in `/reputation`.

Because of migrated and deleted questions, there will probably always be *some* difference, but in this case, one of the reputation calculators is simply broken.

---

### Hypothesis

When downvoting an answer, the **site** removes 1 reputation, and reduces the daily reputation cap by 1. One downvote means that reputation from upvotes only is capped at 199.

The **`/reputation`** page removes 1 reputation, but the daily cap is not reduced. More than 20 answer upvotes will still gain a user 200 reputation.

---

### Data

This is yesterday's reputation report:

```
     2    384380 (10)
     1    384689 (15)
     2    384689 (10)
     3    384528 (-1)
     2    384713 (5)
     2    384713 (5)
     2    384713 (5)
     1    384735 (2)
     1    373133 (15)
     2    384770 (10)
     2    384770 (10)
     2    384770 (10)
     2    384770 (10)
     1    384770 (15)
     2    384770 (10)
     2    384770 (10)
     2    384770 (10)
     2    384770 (10) *
     2    384873 (10)
     2    384880 (10)
     2    384880 (10)
     1    384859 (15)
     2    384859 (10)
     2    384880 (10)
     2    384770 (10)
     2    384873 (10)
     2    384859 (10)
     2    384770 [6]
    -- 2012-02-01 rep +262  = 30079
```

Around the time of the `*` marked line (+/–1), I manually triggered a reputation recalc that reduced my reputation from 30,003 to 29,978.

At the end of the UTC day, I had 30,078 reputation.

[image]

The very last upvote was only worth 5 points, from 30,073 to 30,078 on the site.

> [image]

The `/reputation` data says it's worth 6. All votes are the same as listed in the *reputation* tab of my user profile.

---

This unnecessary discrepancy is the **bug**.

Comment: We're in the middle of heavily refactoring how rep changes are surfaced to the user.  Give us another week and this will be fixed.

Comment: @JarrodDixon You can probably assign a final status now?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me!